# Windows playback device to a different Windows PC's recording device

Tags: windows-7, networking, audio

I need to find some way to send audio, in real time, from one Windows PC's playback device output to a different PCs recording device input.

The computers are close enough to each other to be connected by wires, and they are also on the same local area network.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from connecting the Line Out from one computer to the Line In of the other with a standard 3.5mm aux cable?

Comment: @Zel, that was my first thought, but it sounds absolutely terrible. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

Run a cable from the **green** line out jack behind your first computer to the **blue** line in jack behind your second computer.

[image: Line in]

I can only describe the next part for Windows 7, but it ought to be similar on newer versions.  Right-click the volume icon in the system tray and select Recording Devices.  You should see Line In on the list now.  Make sure it's set default, then click properties.  On the Listen tab, you can check a box to echo everything to that second computer's speakers for testing.  On the Levels tab, turn the volume up to 100%, and on the Advanced tab turn the audio quality as high as it can go.

It's possible the audio chipset on one of your computers is just poor, but this is how I tested things on my own systems and music is sounding the same as if I were playing it on the receiving computer directly.

Comment: So, if it does turn out that one of the audio chipsets is poor, will getting a fairly cheap sound card help the issue?

Comment: Also, will the recognition of "Line In" and "Line Out" audio devices be any different if either of the computers have the Realtek Audio Manager software?

Comment: First question, that's hard to say.  Cheap is cheap for a reason.  It can, if poor/noisy onboard audio is the cause of the problem, and you can figure out which side has the issue.  I assume native audio sounds fine when played through speakers on both systems.  Might want to try sending audio in the other direction just to test it, also.  As for recognition of the wires, just verify the settings in the audio manager on both systems to make sure everything is what it should be.  My systems aren't Realtek, so I can't really say.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest physical solution is to do as @Zel suggests; i.e. use a standard audio cable from earphone out to mic in. That said, the sound fidelity will be somewhat limited by the audio power output driver and microphone amplifier.

An alternative is to use software such as the [VB Virtual Audio Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm) to send the audio output to another device via RF, such as Bluetooth or WiFi (e.g. through [WiPeer](http://download.cnet.com/WiPeer/3000-12941_4-10650668.html)), or through an internet radio server such as [Icecast](http://icecast.org/). Basically, you'd be implementing audio network streaming. N.B. I have not tried this myself, but it should work, with a bit of effort.

Comment: The downside to streaming is that the audio signal will likely get compressed.  But if his computer has actual line in/out ports, rather than just a headphone and microphone jack, it should work without any notable loss in signal quality.  Granted that won't be a good option if one of his systems is a laptop.

Comment: @Zel, they are both desktop PCs. So can you suggest a way to prevent loss in quality when directly connecting them? As I said, right now the sound quality is terrible when I do that.

Comment: As you state, line-out and line-in are optimal.